# Using PostgreSql Geograhy Type in R

Tags: r, postgresql, spatial

I try to use PostgreSql + R, but unfortunately one of column has geography type and in R :

> class(p43231$Polygon)
> [1] "pq_geography"

I cannt use it is a spatial data:

sf_data <- st_as_sf(p43231, wkb = "p43231$Polygon")

I got an error : Error in st_sf(x, ..., agr = agr, sf_column_name = sf_column_name) :
no simple features geometry column present

I think it is because I use geography type in Postgre instead of geometry. How can I use geography in R?

Comment: Are you using Postgis with Postgres (PG) or are you using the geometry type in PG (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-geometric.html). My guess is that you are using the second one because {sf} works totally fine with Postgis types. Can you post how are formatted a small polygon in the DB so we can do better than guessing ? Also naming the geometry column "polygon" is not very frequent.